# onTouch event blocking use of other controls

Tags: javascript, ios, touch

I've been playing around with the [Padilicious](http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/index.html) touch events script after researching a problem I'm seeing in my code. I am able to recreate my own issues with the Padilicious script. I'm simply adding a form with an input to this example provided on the Padilicious site.

When I load this up on an iPad or on an iPhone emulator on a Mac, I'm unable to gain focus on the textbox. In my code, this has the same effect by blocking access to divs and other controls in the site's content. It's as if the div containing the ontouch events is masking everything else inside it.

Here is a jsfiddle showing what I've added. http://jsfiddle.net/Da8yj/

How can I impliment this swiping functionality and also keep the current functionality of my other controls?